# How to save matlab figure with brushed elements

Tags: matlab, charts, save, matlab-figure, brush

In MATLAB i can save chart using `File`->`Save As`, and saving it as figure `.fig`. But it did not save items which i brushed on.

How can i save chart with brushed items?

I open figure using command:
`uiopen('C:\Users\user\Desktop\MATLAB\2.fig',1)`

Comment: You might have to export the data to a separate variable and store that in a .mat file. For ease you could then write a function to load a figure and "re-brush" the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is not necessary to save the figure as .fig , the brushing informations can be kept if figure is saved in image format such as png,jpg.

example:

```
plot([1:10],[1:10])
```

Do all the brushing you need on the figure and then

```
saveas(gcf,'FigureBrushed.png')
```

you can use the following to display the image.

```
im = imread('FigureBrushed.png');
imshow(im)
```

Note: You will lose the arrays information (The values of X,Y -- they will be just displayed in the image but not as an array), you might need to save the fig or the workspace as well to keep all information of your plot (X,Y Values).